# Rails app may be crashing passenger, not sure how to debug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, passenger

My app generates some image data on the fly and sends it back to the browser with `send_data some_huge_blob, :type => 'image/png'`. This works well enough in development mode, but in production with nginx/passenger in the mix it appears as if sometimes passenger just crashes. Here is the debug output in my nginx log

```
[ pid=596 thr=140172782794496 file=ext/common/ApplicationPool/Pool.h:1162 time=2011-07-25 23:15:14.965 ]: Exception occurred while connecting to checked out process 1428: Cannot connect to Unix socket '/tmp/passenger.1.0.589/generation-0/backends/ruby.kJRjXYuZteKoogZIufN8a2cDPdpbIlYmIr1hh3G9UV7GhKDB4pqZ5y0jR': Connection refused (111)
[ pid=596 thr=140172782794496 file=ext/common/ApplicationPool/Pool.h:685 time=2011-07-25 23:15:14.965 ]: Detaching process 1428
[ pid=596 thr=140172782794496 file=ext/common/ApplicationPool/../Process.h:138 time=2011-07-25 23:15:14.969 ]: Application process 1428 (0x2676ee0): destroyed.
[ pid=1405 thr=70178806733240 file=abstract_request_handler.rb:466 time=2011-07-25 23:15:14.982 ]: Accepting new request on main socket
2011/07/25 23:15:16 [error] 642#0: *96 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 173.8.216.57, server: app.somedomain.com, request: "GET /projects/4e2dee4c106a821bf2000008/revisions/1/assets/Layout2.psd/preview HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "app.somedomain.com"
```

Note that there is nothing in my `production.log` file that indicates the request even makes it to the app!

Any ideas? Or ideas as to how to debug this further? The `connection refused` bit is interesting...

For what it's worth, this is an Ubuntu image on a micro instance in AWS.

Comment: Have you ever solved this? I'm getting the same error.